# How to add comment below shipping details in Woocommerce checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On the woocommerce checkout page, there is a shipping option section. I have two options on my store which are collection (available to all users) and a free delivery option (available to only customers with certain postcodes). These are set-up using the advanced shipping methods plugin.

I want to add a comment/text below the shipping options to let users know why they cant see the free shipping method. Something like "you cant select free delivery because your not within our delivery area."

Can anyone help accomplish this?

Screenshot example of what I want to achieve:

[image: Screenshot example of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Can you provide the code you are currently using?

Comment: That is the problem when using 3rd party plugins: you get the limitations of the plugin that is not handling what you would like. So now you could Ask the author of this plugin in his support threads (He use to answer in stackOverFlow, sometimes rarely)…

Answer (score 0):

copy the file wp-content\plugins\woocommerce-elementor\woocommerce\templates\cart\cart-shipping.php to
yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-shipping.php
and add your comment to given relevant location